# How should I abort the client if there are no servers running?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

How can one check if a server is listening or not for below RPC client server call?

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html

Answer (score 1):

Give to either the message or the queue a time-out:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

The client needs to

- declare the [dead-letter exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html)
- bind a queue to it
- consume dead-messages from it

If it receives the dead-message request previously sent, than no server has consumed the message within the time-out and can behave consequently.